# aggregate directories with lapply

Tags: r, bioinformatics, data-manipulation

[MWE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwzvabicbrbuxne/mwe.zip?dl=0)

I have whole-genome data for approximately 100 individuals in 4 populations. Each population has a separate directory containing separate files for each individual. I am attempting to clean it all up and aggregate it to one data frame using this code:

```
popAgg <- function (dir){
  fileNames <- list.files(path = dir , full.names = TRUE)
  data <- lapply (
    X = seq_along(fileNames) , FUN = function (x) {
      cbind (x , read.csv (fileNames[x] , sep = "\t", header = FALSE))
    }
  )
popData <- rbind.fill(data)
popData <- cbind (dir , popData)
popData <- popData[popData[14]!=0, c(1 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 14)]
names(popData) <- c("pop" , "ind" , "read.depth" , "position", "no.diff")
return(popData)
}
dirNames <- list.dirs()
metaPopData <- lapply(X = dirNames , FUN = popAgg)
```

This should give me a list of data frames which can then be collapsed with `rbind.fill`.

Ultimately, the output given the attached mwe should give me:

```
      pop ind read.depth position no.diff
27  MWE1/   2        382      437     418
271 MWE2/   2        382      437     418
```

I used the `popAgg` function to derive this output by manually applying to both directories in the mwe, so it looks like `lapply` is the only problem I am having and seems to be the source of the error. Furthermore, I used the same technique in the `popAgg` function, aside from writing the function as a lambda, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by setting `recursive = FALSE` in `list.dirs(...)`.